# Why can't i find/use dependency <>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc<>

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, pom.xml, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The project is telling me to add this dependency and remove the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency but i am receiving the error that that dependency is not found.  I can't find any updates as of right now so was wondering if anyone knows what the issue is

Usually theres something online stating how this dependency isn't used anymore or an updated version, but i can't seem to find one.

Comment: [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc) are all the supported versions.